# User name in the upper right hand corner

Tags: website-design

One of the worst thing from performance point of view is the user name in the upper right hand corner. It is a perfectly static page. Absolutely cacheable. But we have to place a unique name in it. It ruins the cache.

Could you tell me whether people really expect to see their username there?
What happens if instead of username an icon is placed? Example: StackOverflow.

Comment: First of all I'd ask if you have a true **measured** performance hit because page can't be cached. Then I'd consider why page content is so heavy to be loaded. If it's _simply_ a static page then you may consider to move that HTML bit (user name and login state) into a separate HTTP call (or an AJAX request)

Comment: This is not for discussion. Because it has nothing to do with the question. The question was: whether user name is necessary or not in the page. The presence of it make things a bit more complex. But one can cope with those complexities.

Comment: OK, I considered the first paragraph as part of the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hmmm

The first bit of the question doesn't make much sense but the second part I can maybe help out with.

Having a user name visible somewhere is useful because it gives the user *visibility of the state of the system* "I am logged in" and is therefore important.

Traditionally the logged in state has been carried in the header region, the position of which tends to be far right by convention but it can vary. Stackexchange carries the state virtually center and I dare say some sites carry it left.

"What happens if instead of username an icon is placed?" then you remove visibility of the logged in state and this is not a good thing. Leave user name in place.